# PHP something wrong with refrence variable in foreach

Tags: php, foreach, php-7.2

I had data like this:

```
$a = [
"attr1"=> null,
"list"=> [
    [
        "other_attr"=> 47,
        "personal"=> [
            [
                "id"=> 3071,
                "quantity"=> 4,
                "price"=> 340000
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        "other_attr"=> 47,
        "group"=> [
            [
                "id"=> 3086,
                "quantity"=> 2,
                "price"=> 350000
            ]
        ]
    ]
]];
```

and with function bellow:

```
foreach( $a['list'] as &$value ){
if (!empty($value["personal"])) {
    foreach ($value["personal"] as &$item) {
        $item['F'] = "TREDA";
    }
    foreach ($value["personal"] as $item) {
        print("do some thing here with new attribute F\n");
    }
    $value["C"] = 32213;
}
 if (!empty($value["group"])) {
     foreach  ($value['group'] as $item) {
         print("Do some thing here\n");
     }
    $value["C"] = "AAAA";
}
}
```

expect result of **$a** after function like this:

```
{"attr1":null,"list":[{"other_attr":47,"personal":[{"id":3071,"quantity":4,"price":340000,"F":"TREDA"}],"C":32213},{"other_attr":47,"group":[{"id":3086,"quantity":2,"price":350000}],"C":"AAAA"}]}
```

but actual data wrong below:

```
{"attr1":null,"list":[{"other_attr":47,"personal":[{"id":3086,"quantity":2,"price":350000}],"C":32213},{"other_attr":47,"group":[{"id":3086,"quantity":2,"price":350000}],"C":"AAAA"}]}
```

**Id 3071** had been replace by **Id 3086**.

Anyone can explain me something wrong here?

Thanks for help!

P/S code demo in link [PHPOnline Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/50505acee6beaf86eb36c442ff6f86a4d155b5df)

Comment: You need to add `unset($item);` after you update/modify `$item` in first `foreach` loop of `$value['personal']`

Comment: Updated on provided sandbox link

Comment: Quote from [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php): `Warning
Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset(). Otherwise you will experience the following behavior`

Comment: This would work just fine http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1c6a0b363ce23dd82ad27efe8db8aef6292919b9

Comment: Unforunately, PHP doesn't maintain local scope of variables inside a loop(unlike Java, for example). See example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/548cb7a33267b0b142424c6b0f37a681b1b24683 So, further reference to the same variable can lead to undefined behavior in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Passing by reference can be a dangerous game, as you've found out. It might not be obvious, but you created a reference to `$item` inside this loop:

```
foreach ($value["personal"] as &$item) {
```

Which then continued to be a reference to the first entry in `$value["personal"]` even though you're not in that loop anymore. So that means that later on in your code when you do:

```
foreach ($value['group'] as $item) {
```

You're referencing the same `$item` variable (which is a reference to the entry inside `$value["personal"]`.

Because of this the entry inside `personal` gets replaced with the entry from inside `group`.

If you don't really need references you'd be better off (and safer) to use the array indices to change the values, like

```
foreach ($value["personal"] as $index => $item) {
    $item['F'] = "TREDA";
    $value['personal'][$index] = $item;
}
```